# Has the fine structure constant been derived from theory?

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, quantum-gravity, physical-constants

The following paper from this year claims to have derived the [fine structure constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine-structure_constant):

> Singh, T.P. *Quantum gravity effects in the infrared: a theoretical derivation of the low-energy fine structure constant and mass ratios of elementary particles.* Eur. Phys. J. Plus 137, 664 (2022). https://doi.org/10.1140/epjp/s13360-022-02868-4 , https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.06614

can someone please explain the physics behind this?

Comment: Related: https://arxiv.org/abs/2110.07548

Comment: *Has the fine structure constant been derived from theory?* - No.

Comment: Note that this paper on arXiv is under “General Physics” rather than “High Energy Physics — Theory” as one would expect for a paper on quantum gravity. My understanding is that such a categorization for such a paper is one step short of rejection from arXiv. It has been banished to a category that no one doing quantum gravity typically reads.

Comment: @Ghoster Peer review and the world around is pretty broken, it would be better to dismiss a paper based on logical mistakes, not based on where it is published.  In the same way we should not trust blindly a paper published on a "top" journal.

Comment: The actual calculation is in equation 59. The raw material are the matrix eigenvalues in figure 3 on page 19. But the theory itself, in my understanding, is full of leaps of wishful thinking and peculiar claims.